# Does the Iran-China pact give the USA an option for slapping China with a large scale sanction?

Tags: united-states, china, iran

Recently, the news is floating on the internet: [Iran and China are negotiating a deal of $400 billion](https://www.express.co.uk/news/world/1309601/world-war-3-Iran-china-us-Beijing-Tehran-news) for seamless supply of oil for 25 years.

Does the pact give the USA an option for slapping China with a large scale sanction?

If yes, on what ground the USA can slap the sanction in this case?

Answer (score 4):

A nation has the right **not** to trade with anybody they don't like. They even have the right **not** to trade with anybody who trades with anybody they don't like. No pretext is necessary, really. Passing such sanctions on a whim might run afoul of international trade treaties, but a nation has the right **not** to be a member of the WTO, or not to sign any bilateral or multilateral investment protection treaties.

So the United States have to ask themselves if either direct or secondary sanctions hurt them or China more, politically and economically. And if they want the rest of the world to match their sanctions, they will have to make the political case.

The US has a tendency to codify their sanctions decision in *domestic* law, but that's just *domestic* law, for the US to alter as they see fit.